# SSRS report builder 2014 CDbl precision

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I have some column in my report, calculated the `Sum` using this exepression :

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields!Type.Value = 0, CDbl(Fields!Amount.Value), CDbl(0.0)))
```

it works but gives me the sum with no precision. 
is there a way I can view the Sum with precision?

**UPDATE**

the `Fields!Amount.Value` is alway decimal(18, 3) 
If The calculation was like `sum = 10 + 10` the result becomes `20`
if `sum = 10 + 2.125` the result becomes `12.125`

I want the result to be converted to (18, 3). 
so I expect the result in the first example to be `20.000`

Comment: What do you mean by `precision`?  Please provide an example of the data you are using, the results your expression is providing and the results you are expecting.

Comment: Updated the question.

Comment: Format the cell a n3. should do the trick

Comment: @Snowlockk Formatting the cell solved the issue. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your report is correctly returning the values to the necessary precision, it is just only showing the significant figures because you have not told it what number formatting you require and is making a best guess.

If you change your expression to the below, you should get your desired output:

```
=FORMAT(SUM(IIF(Fields!Type.Value = 0, CDbl(Fields!Amount.Value), CDbl(0.0))),"0.000")
```